# PHP custom exception message

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

I'm trying to display a custom error message if a method doesnt' exist as `Method()` or as `getMethod()`:

```
public function __call($name, $args = array()){
  $getter = "get{$name}";

  try {
    echo call_user_func_array(array(&$this, $getter), $args);
  } catch (Exception $e) {

    trigger_error($e->getFile.' on line '.$e->getLine.': Method '.$name.' is not defined.', E_USER_ERROR)
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work. I get a "connection closed by remote server" message in the browser :|

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php

Comment: yes I know about that, but I want to use this try catch thing because it tells me the line / file where the error is

Comment: Alex you know how to throw an exception ?

Comment: and why would I do that? what's a expection?

Comment: @Alex: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018486/what-is-an-exception-in-php-for-and-what-is-try-and-catch

Comment: @Alex: you know how to use try..catch but you don't know what's an exception? (@tomalak: now you can't say me I am rude here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the [`method_exists`](http://php.net/method_exists) function:

```
if(!method_exists($this, $name))
{
    // trigger_error(...);
}
```

If you wanted data such as where the invalid method was called from, you can use [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/debug_backtrace):

```
class X
{
    public function __call($name, $a)
    {
        $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
        $backtrace = $backtrace[1];
        // $backtrace['file']
        // $backtrace['line']
        // $backtrace['function']
        // $backtrace['class']
        // $backtrace['object']
    }
}

$o = new X();
$o->Hello();
```

Comment: @Alex: Yes, check my answer. Just access those array elements that I have listed.

Comment: you only need to throw new Exception('...');